# How do I get Ctrl+Left / Ctrl+Right to jump a word again in byobu?

Tags: shortcut-keys, byobu, virtual-console

On my Ubuntu 11.10 machines running byobu 4.37 I can use the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to jump a word at a time in the terminal. However, on my Ubuntu 12.04 machines with byobu 5.17 this no longer works.

I've read that byobu has remapped those key combinations to resize splits, and now <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> have the desired effect. However, I'm unable to find where <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> are mapped, in order to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>. If I unmap the key bindings for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>, then the cursor moves only 1 character at a time, not 1 word at a time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution was to switch the backend to screen. However, I had recurring issues with ctrl-right when I did that. To do that change `~/.byobu/backend` to `BYOBU_BACKEND=screen`.

I subsequently found a much better solution using tmux from [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/byobu/+bug/945069). Create `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf` with this value:

```
set-window-option -g xterm-keys on
```

Then `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux` with:

```
unbind-key -n C-Left
unbind-key -n C-Right
```

Now ctrl-left and ctrl-right jump one word at a time in tmux.

Answer (score 1):

In my `~/.zshrc`

```
bindkey '^[[1;5D' backward-word
bindkey '^[[1;5C' forward-word
```

... And now `ctrl+left / right` jump words in byobu / tmux.

Comment: That's a useful trick. I guess it only works for zsh shells. Personally, I'm using zsh locally, but bash everywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the change is because now Byobu is using `tmux` as the backend, instead of `screen`.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Left</kbd> & <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd> are used in `tmux` for navigating panes, so we have to tell `tmux` not to do this! Just edit your `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux` and add the following lines to the end:

```
unbind-key -n C-Left
unbind-key -n C-Right
```

Just log out/back in and you should see the change.

*Note, this will only work for `xterm`, not for the actual `ttys`. You will notice that even without using `byobu`, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>right</kbd> do not behave as expected from a `tty`. Ubuntu seems to ignore `/etc/inputrc` when using a `tty` for some reason.

Comment: I tried that, but then ctrl-left/right only moves one character at a time, not a whole word.

Comment: I can confirm @chmac's solution.

Comment: good answer, but it didn't work for me without the `.tmux.conf` changes