# Disable keybindings in byobu using tmux backend

Tags: shortcut-keys, vim, byobu, tmux

I've setup the `alt + arrow keys` bindings for changing tab in `vim` (in `.vimrc`):

```
map <silent><A-Right> :tabnext<CR> 
map <silent><A-Left> :tabprevious<CR>
```

this however does not work under `byobu` with `tmux` backend, I guess because it is remapped by `byobu`.

I tried setting:

```
unbind -n M-right
unbind -n M-left
```

in `.tmux.conf` or `.byobu/keybindings.tmux` without success.

Anyone has a suggestion on how to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're so close!  You're just missing the capitalization of "R" in M-Right and "L" in M-Left.

Just add the following to `~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux`:

```
unbind -n M-Right
unbind -n M-Left
```

And then press <kbd>F5</kbd> to reload your profile.

*Full Disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: thanks! but still it doesn't work, Alt-left and Alt-right still move word by word. And my vim keybindings do not work. I tried both uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: Hmm, I made the same mistake in my instructions.  Try what's above.  That's working perfectly for me...

Comment: tried again with this configuration, also created a new user just to test this, still it does not work. I have byobu version 5.17
tmux 1.6 on 12.04.2 LTS.

Comment: Hmm, can you try updating to the latest Byobu release from the ppa?  `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:byobu/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y byobu`

Comment: thanks, updated to: `byobu version 5.55 tmux 1.6`, but still does not work. tested with no success also on another Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS. I had to create `keybindings.tmux` myself, is it possible that it is not actually read?

Comment: Hmm, you have something else going on here, I'm afraid.  I've tested this on 3 different system, and it's working as described across the board...  Perhaps try moving your ~/.byobu out of the way, and letting Byobu create a new one for you.

Comment: no way, now it correctly created `keybindings.tmux` for me, I added the `unbind` commands, run `byobu-tmux`, press F5, but still it moves word by word.

Comment: I'll mark the answer as accepted, there must be something wrong in my systems.

Comment: I also needed the settings in `.tmux.conf` from here: http://askubuntu.com/a/145227/198237

Comment: I initially did similar unbinds in ~/.byobu/.tmux.conf, and it worked, but toggling Byobu F-keys off and back on (with Shift-F12) lost the unbinds. 
So, you indeed need to do this in ~/.byobu/keybindings.tmux, or Byobu won't pick it up correctly.

Answer (score 5):

If you cannot manage to disable specific keybindings, you can toggle Byobu's keybindings off/on using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> – which is what I use a lot (e.g. to interact with Midnight Commander). I just miss a possibility to have the current status of that displayed in the status bar (are keybindings currently active – or have I turned them off?) – but that's a different issue ;)

Comment: thank you for the shortcut, and I totally agree with you regarding the latter case

Comment: Thank you for this! I've accidentally disabled those and this is what re-enabled them.