# Tmux: jumping over words in the terminal

Tags: tmux

In a regular terminal (i.e. no multiplexer) I can use the combination of `Ctrl-Left/Right arrows` to jump over several words. However, in tmux I am not able to do that.

PS: I am still reading Tmux by Brian P. Hogan.

PS 2: I am using Zsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To jump over words enable xterm-keys: `set-window-option -g xterm-keys on`

[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/145227/110181)